# Autofac: Resolve Based on a Condition/Parameter to Remove Switch Statements for Instantiation

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

Imagine a large switch statement that instantiates different classes:

```
switch (typeIdentifier)
{
    case SomeEnum.Type1:
        instantiatedObject = new Type1Class(...);
        break;
    ...
}
```

Type1Class, Type2Class, ..., TypeNClass, all inherit from a common abstract class. I would like to replace the entire switch statement with something like:

```
scope.Resolve<TheAbstractClass>(...);
```

However, it needs to resolve to the right class based on the value of typeIdentifier. I am wondering if this is possible and if so, how?

One solution would be to forgo autofac entirely, and simply have a dictionary of delegates that instantiate the right class. But, my preference is to use autofac out of simplicity. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple options available in Autofac, which are knowns as `Keyed`, `Named` to achieve this.

Below code sample is for `Named`-

Register -

```
 containerBuilder.RegisterType<Type1Class>().Named<ITestItem>("Type1");
```

Resolve -

```
var testItem = container.ResolveNamed<ITestItem>("Type1");
```

You can refer to the link https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html for more details.